# Powershell Could not load file or assembly one of its dependencies. if dll is build and loaded

Tags: c#, powershell, dll

When i tried to load the dll which i have just build on my machine and copied to other location from where i want to load and execute it, it complains following 
"Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies, even if i have loaded all dlls."

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName <dll name> 
Add-Type -AssemblyName <dll path> 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("path to .dll").
```

I have loaded all the reference dlls, still it reports the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

After some hit and trial I come to know that if we want to load the newly build dll in powershell then all required dll (specific versions or exact same)needs to be loaded which was used as reference dll during Build.